# Find duplicates in multidemnsional array, remove one PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have multidemensional array where are the keys `name` ​​with and without duplicates and i need to return final array without duplicates and one from duplicate where key `amount` is smaller.

For ex:

```
$tmp = [['name' => 'red', 'amount' => 20], 
        ['name' => 'green', 'amount' => 20], 
        ['name' => 'green', 'amount' => 40]];
```

final array should be:

```
$finalArray = [['name' => 'red', 'amount' => 20], 
                ['name' => 'green', 'amount' => 20]]
```

Comment: If you can read it, there is just a vague danger you can understand/debug it :)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are a bunch of functions to [filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter) arrays, [walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) arrays or [map](https://www.php.net/array_map) array elements. Which have you tried?

Comment: With what logic should you delete the same key with different value?

Comment: You can create two loops and check each value to add it to an new array.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini To be fair the OP did say they want to keep the one with the smallest value of amount

Comment: @RiggsFolly right, i didn't see :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function in php to handle just this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: The array structure in the question is different and your answer doesn't take in account the `amount`.